# force browser to add horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: css, image, html

Just wondering if there's some way to force the browser to bring up the horizontal scroll bar. My problem is that I have some images in a div and they "overflow" out of it when I make the window smaller. I would rather not use the overflow property nor do I want to resize the images.

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Huh? If they overflow out of the window, the scrollbars will come up by default.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I mean that they overflow out of the div when I make the browser window smaller. It's not until the browser window reaches the images that the scroll bar shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, I'm such a noob. All I needed to do was add this to my scripts:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if($(window).width() <= 1200)
    $("body").css("width","1200px");
else
$("body").css("width","100%");
});
```

This does exactly what I wanted it to do.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Do you realize you could've just used `min-width: 1200px`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the CSS3 `overflow-x` property to force scroll:

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

Tie that into a Javascript onresize callback and you should be all set.

Comment: I would like a scrollbar for the entire page, not the div itself.

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow` directly on the body tag (maybe in combination with some `width` settings/adjustments)